# Prevent null for enum

Tags: java, enums

Is there a way to make an enum in Java that cannot be null?

Alternately, can a newly-declared enum have a default value the same way boolean defaults to false and number types default to 0?

Comment: You could always have a `NONE` value to correspond to the default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to make an enum in Java that cannot be null?

No.

> Alternately, can a newly-declared enum have a default value the same way boolean defaults to false and number types default to 0?

No.

The default value for any reference type is null.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, no.  You seem to misunderstand what an enum actually is.  Enums in Java are really just syntactic sugar for a class with a private constructor and some public static final instances of itself.  (It's a little more complex than that, but that's fundamentally what it is.)  If you declare a variable whose type is an enum, it's really no different from a variable whose declared type is any other class.  And the default value for any reference variable is null.

Comment: The *purpose* of an emum is to have a fixed set of enumerated values. The way it's implemented in Java adds an additional value: null. I'm asking if there is a way to eliminate that value for an enum, and the answer is clearly "no".

Comment: Well, your question prompted me to learn something.  I never thought much about the fact that null *is* a value; I only thought of it as the *absence* of value.  I knew that `Double.NaN != Double.NaN`, but I didn't know that `null == null`.